# Bring DIV in front of iframe FLASH

Tags: css, iframe, html, flash

I have the following structure in my `html`:

```
<div style='position:absolute; top:40px; left:0; height:cH; width:100%;>
    <iframe width='100%' height='100%' noresize='noresize' frameborder='0' />
</div>
```

And I have a `SWF flash` object in my `iframe`. How can I show it underneath my div?

It's a dynamic page, **I can't access the .swf to edit any settings like opacity**.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to access the `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` section

if you can't - youre out of luck.

p.s.

also for

```
 wmode 
="opaque"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can z index help you?

You define iframe with low index and div with high one...

[w3schools - z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

*The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.*